# How can I discover if an object contains numeric fields that are set to 0?

Tags: java

How can I discover (using reflection, probably) if a Java object contains numeric fields that are set to the value `0`? I was thinking something like this:

```
public boolean checkZero(Class T){
   return false; 
   // need help here 
}
```

However `T` doesn't have a method which will check for the values.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're after. Can you clarify? What does it mean for a class to "contain 0 value"?

Comment: Your first version of the question was better.

Comment: Hi Michael. I want my method to check if some class contains parameters with 0 values. Is it possible?

Comment: Still not clear. Do you mean you want to find numeric fields that contain the value '0'? @Joseph, do you have a link to the earlier, clearer question?

Comment: Yes. :) @MichaelPetrotta

Comment: You mean if Object of Class has field that stores 0 value? Or maybe if class has fields that are by default 0? Or maybe something else?

Comment: Could you show how this class should look like, when that method should return true and false?

Comment: What I meant here is if object of class has number fields equals to 0. @Pshemo

Comment: @romedius It will be then called somewhere and do formulation of seeking inside my class whether or not some of that class fields contains 0 or not.

Comment: @Micheal: When I first looked at this question, the OP made two or three revisions within the first minute, which SO doesn't seem to keep. But it isn't worth pursuing.

Comment: If you don't know anything about the class, you'll need to use reflection.

Comment: How does this rate 12 comments? (Todo: delete this comment)

Comment: @TedHopp is there some example of how can I achieve it?

Comment: Takarakaka, I've fairly severely rewritten your question - hopefully I've captured what you're looking for.

Comment: Can we ask _why_ you would want this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this:

```
     public boolean checkZero(Class clazz){
        boolean zeroNumericFields = true;
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        boolean zeroNumericFields = true;
        List<Class> numberClasses = new ArrayList<Class>();

        //Add all types you want to check e.g.
        numberClasses.add(Number.class);
        numberClasses.add(Integer.class);
        numberClasses.add(Long.class);
        numberClasses.add(Double.class);
        numberClasses.add(Float.class);

        if(fields.length > 0){
           for(Field field : fields){
               if(numberClasses.contains(field.getType())){
                   zeroNumericFields = false;
                   break;
               }
            }
        }
        return zeroNumericFields;
     }
```

Please Note: This excludes, inherited fields, if any.

Comment: @Vulcan: I added the logic to check the types as well.

Comment: Where do you check if the *value* is `0`? You cannot do that without an `Object`

Comment: @Takarakaka: Wait for couple minutes, I need to make a small correction.

Comment: @Takarakaka: Made one small correction. It seems to be working i.e. counts the numric fields declared in the class and return false, if any. Please test the updated code.

Comment: @MiserableVariable: I read this in comments from OP: "What I meant here is if object of class has number fields equals to 0"

Comment: OP wants to check if *value* of any numeric field is equal 0, not if there are numeric fields.

Comment: @Pshemo: This is what I read one of the comments from OP- "What I meant here is if object of class has number fields equals to 0".

Comment: @YogendraSingh You might be right, but on the other hand we can read in question comments: "whether or not some of that class fields contains 0 or not". Guess we wont find out what OP wants until he/she chose answer that solves this problem :)

Comment: @Pshemo: Agree. It's bit confusing. As I mentioned, I answered the version where it was around count.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is what you want but lets try it :)

```
static boolean checkZeroes(Object o) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException {

    Field[] fields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field f : fields) {
        // lets check what is inside of field
        f.setAccessible(true);// in case of private field
        Object value = f.get(o);

        System.out.println("checking " + f + ": " + value);
        if (value.equals((byte) 0) 
            || value.equals((short) 0)
            || value.equals((int) 0)
            || value.equals((long) 0)
            || value.equals((float) 0)
            || value.equals((double) 0)
            ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But would that harm to my security in any way, if I set my private fields to be accessible?

Comment: Thats one of reasons I am not sure if this solution is what you wanted. You don't have to use `f.setAccessible(true)` if you don't want to :)

Comment: @Takarakaka `f.setAccessible(true)` wont permanent change accessibility of field, but just let `f` reference get value of that field from your object.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean checkZero(Class T){
```

Is incorrect for

> [checking] if a Java object contains...

What you need is

```
public boolean checkZero(Object o){
```

Now that you have an `Object`,

- Use [`Object.getclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) to gets its `Class`
- Use [`Class.getFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29) to get its fields
- Use [`Field.getType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29) to get the field's class
- Check if the field's class is Numeric
- User [`setAccessible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) to be able to access the potentially private field. This can fail in some cases, check the documentation.
- Use [`Field.get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) to get the value of that field
- Cast it correct static type and compare with 0.

Comment: Excellent answer! Will check it now if I can manage to do what I wanted to do by using it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the class' declared fields and get their values.  However, you will also need an instance of that class from which to acquire the values.

```
public static boolean checkZero(Object toCheck) {
    final Class<?> numerics = new Class<?>[]{ int.class, double.class, float.class,
            long.class, short.class, byte.class, Integer.class, Double.class,
            Float.class, Long.class, Short.class, Byte.class };
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = toCheck.getClass();
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            Class<?> type = field.getType();
            boolean isNumeric = false;
            for (Class<?> numeric : numerics) {
                if (type.equals(numeric)) {
                    isNumeric = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isNumeric) {
                Object value = field.get(toCheck);
                if (value == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

The only possible issue with this is comparing primitive fields in an Object form.  You might need to make special cases using Field#getInt, Field#getDouble, and so forth for checking the value against zero.